# Hide Download files page (IDP)?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

I use "Inno download plugin" in my inno installer, I wish to download the files before I get to "wpInstalling" and to hide the IDP download page,
Now here is the problems I encountered:

1. If I use "idpAddFile" function i must specify "idpDownloadAfter" and thus i cant hide the IDP download page from the user
2. If i use "idpDownloadFile" function my inno setup becomes "slaggy" and slow for some strange reason

Comment: "slaggy"? If you mean it's slow/ unresponsive UI, it will be as it's downloading it as a blocking operation, and everything else (including the UI) has to wait.

Comment: is there a way to hide the IDP  DOWNLOAD page?

Comment: Not really. What would you show in its place? If nothing, you'd just end up with exactly the same as when using `idpDownloadFile` and the installer being unresponsive for a short period of time.

Comment: I wished the download and install processes will be one ans not separated

Comment: You can't do that with Inno Setup as it stands at the moment without overriding the entire installer progress bar.