# Display a page/message before idpDownloadFile

Tags: inno-setup

I wish to show the user a page or a message screen saying "The setup will begin shortly" just before/while until `idpDownloadFile` will finish to download.
I need this page/message to make UX better, Currently when the user double click the setup.exe the setup loads 15 sec after he opened it because the setup waits until `idpDownloadFile` finishes and that's a bad UX

Comment: Didn't you just ask [how to remove the progress page while downloading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25175176/588306)?

Comment: yes, I decided to keep the progress page

Comment: So this is a non issue and solved now?

Comment: the Question above is completely different from what I tried to achieve in the previous Question, i wish to present a page before the download starts

Comment: please!, is there a way to present a page before idpDownloadFile starts?

Comment: Doesn't the normal welcome page show before this that contains pretty much the same text?

Comment: The sequence I encounter is as follows:
1. double click on setup 
2. idpDownloadFile download image file (~7sec)
3. first costume page shows
4. second costume page shows
5. idpAddFile download 
6. install page 
7. finish page 

I wish to show the user a "waiting" screen between step 1 and 2

Comment: `CreateCustomPage` (or maybe `CreateProgressPage`). You should know this as you've already created custom pages so I don't get wheat more you're asking for. Showing the original welcome page will also do that.

Comment: I want this "waiting" page to show until the `idpDownloadFile` finish to download , when it finish to download I want immediately to move to the next page, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a page while a long running process is running, like a download, then you can use the `CreateProgressPage`, or `CreateCustomForm`. This can then be hidden when the long running process has finished.

Comment: how do I know when the running process has finished, how do I catch it?

Comment: When `idpDownloadFile` returns. It's a blocking call.

Comment: it wont do, the `idpDownloadFile` starts before any page loads, I placed a waitpage before the `idpDownloadFile` and it dosent work, here - 
`procedure InitializeWizard();

begin
  CreateWaitPage;

  idpDownloadFile(MOImg, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\moimagefile.bmp'));

end;
`

Comment: That's because you're doing it in `InitializeWizard()` which is meant for initializing the wizard, not downloading files. If it really needs to be done before an existing custom page, then do it int he events for that page, maybe `CurPageChanged`. Or just reinstate the normal download progress and tell it to be before your custom page.